# Master equation of chemical reaction

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I have about the construction of master equation for chemical reaction i.e. I have to construct differential equations for the probability mass function for the number of particles A, B and C.

When I have this following reaction 
$$\emptyset\rightarrow^{k_A}{A}$$
$$\emptyset\rightarrow^{k_B}{B}$$
$$A\rightarrow^{k_A}{B}$$
$$B\rightarrow^{\gamma}{\emptyset}$$
I have no problem to construct the master equation because if i consider P(n,m,t), P(n,t), P(m,t) where n is the number of particles A and m the number of particles B at time t I should have the following equations with respect to each reaction (if I'm right):
$$
P'(n,t)=P(n-1,t)k_{A}-P(n,t)k_A
$$
$$
P'(m,t)=P(m-1,t)k_{B}-P(m,t)k_B
$$
$$
P'(m,t)=P(m-1,t)nk_{A}-P(m,t)nk_A
$$
$$
P'(m,t)=P(m+1,t)(m+1)\gamma-P(m,t)\gamma
$$
But for example, when I have to consider more complicated reaction, in which way should I have to procede? 
For example, for the following reaction
$$
A+B\rightarrow^{\gamma}\emptyset
$$
is the following reaction correct?
$$
P'(n,m,t)=P(n+1,m+1,t)(n+1)(m+1)\gamma-P(n,m,t)nm\gamma
$$
And for other kind of reaction like these:
$$
A+B\rightarrow^{\gamma_B}A
$$
$$
A+A\rightarrow^{\gamma_{AA}}\emptyset
$$
$$
A+B\rightarrow^{k_C}C
$$
In which way should I procede? 
I will be very happy if someone could help me! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Sorry but which equation are you suggesting that $P′(n,m,t)$ should solve? Four (different) is three too many...

Comment: The equation that I have suggested at the beginning are for the reaction above, the first equation for P'(n,m,t) should represent the equation for the first reaction ($\emptyset\rightarrow{A}$), the second eqn for the second reaction and so on..

Comment: And I think that I have found also the equation for $A+A\rightarrow{\emptyset}$ that should be $$P'(n,t)=\gamma_{AA}(n+2)(n+1)P(n+2,t)-\gamma_{AA}n(n-1)P(n,t)$$ but I'm not already able to find the other to equations..

Comment: Sorry but this does not make sense. The first reaction is only concerned with particles A so how counting the number of particles B can be relevant? And you wrote "the reaction" (singular) for the system of 4 chemical processes... Please clarify.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe my english is not so good unfortunately eheh.. Yes, you're right, the first two reactions and the last one should not take into account both A and B. Now I will correct.

Comment: @CrishaD What does $\emptyset$ mean?

Comment: Wikipedia: Master equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_equation

Comment: Roussel, M. R.: Foundations of Chemical Kinetics. Lecture 20: The master equation. University of Lethbridge, Department of Chemistry and Biochemistry. http://people.uleth.ca/~roussel/C4000foundations/

Comment: Reis, M.; Kromer, J. A.; Klipp, E.: General solution of the chemical master equation
and modality of marginal distributions for hierarchic first-order reaction networks. J. Math. Biol. 77 (2018) 377–419. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00285-018-1205-2